# Swift, SwiftUI - .getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uicolor

I am following Stanfords' CS193p Developing Apps for iOS online course.

I'm trying to do the [Assignment 6 Memorize.pdf](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/sites/g/files/sbiybj16636/files/media/file/assignment_6.pdf).

It says to use this code below ⬇️, but it gives me always white color. Is there a bug somewhere? Please help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RGBAColor: Codable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let red: Double
    let green: Double
    let blue: Double
    let alpha: Double
}

extension Color {
    init(rgbaColor rgba: RGBAColor) {
        self.init(.sRGB, red: rgba.red, green: rgba.green, blue: rgba.blue, opacity: rgba.alpha)
    }
}

extension RGBAColor {
    init(color: Color) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        if let cgColor = color.cgColor {
            UIColor(cgColor: cgColor).getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        }
        self.init(red: Double(red), green: Double(green), blue: Double(blue), alpha: Double(alpha))
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    static let rgbaColorRed = RGBAColor(color: Color.red)
    static let thisShouldBeRed = Color(rgbaColor: rgbaColorRed)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(ContentView.thisShouldBeRed) // why white here, not red???
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `Color.red` doesn't have a `cgColor`, it seems.

Comment: @LeoDabus Where exactly did the OP pass in a value between 0 and 255?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [`cgColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/cgcolor) property's documentation says:

> For a dynamic color, like one you load from an Asset Catalog using `init(_:bundle:)`, or one you create from a dynamic UIKit or AppKit color, this property is nil.

[`Color.red`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/red-r0xf) is actually a dynamic color:

> A *context-dependent* red color suitable for use in UI elements.

So `Color.red.cgColor` is nil, causing the `getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)` call to not run, and the `red`, `green`, `blue`, `alpha` local variables remain 0. So the color you got is not "white", but "transparent".

You can actually create a `UIColor` directly from `Color`, without going through `CGColor`:

```
var red: CGFloat = 0
var green: CGFloat = 0
var blue: CGFloat = 0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0

// note here:
UIColor(color).getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
self.init(red: Double(red), green: Double(green), blue: Double(blue), alpha: Double(alpha))
```